# JQPlot's Meter Gauge - Show Value in Needle

Tags: javascript, plugins, graph, jqplot

I can't find anywhere how do I put the selected value to appear in the end of needle. All I can do is show the Ticks values but not the exactly value that the needle is showing.

Is there a param to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I checked jqPlot documentation. Even I didn't find an option(in `rendererOptions`)

So, as a quick fix, you can show the value(position) of the needle in the `label` option

I have created a fiddle for the same.
You can check it here : [jqPlot - Meter Gauge with needle value](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/b5g43zb6/1/)

Hope it helps..